# Can (or should) the server send trailers (trailing headers) to the client?

Tags: node.js

Both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 supports trailing headers (headers after the message body)

I'm testing trailers in Node.js server and client, it works as expected from client to server but I can't see tools that support this mechanism from server to client and the documentation doesn't specify it

My question is, Can (or should) the server send trailing headers to the client in the first place?

Comment: What trailing headers would be useful to send to the client?

Comment: Those have an intention, consider post process meta data